# Regex to convert URL to string

Tags: javascript, regex, url

**REGEX ONLY**

I **exclusively need Javascript regex code** to convert URLs like

```
https://hello.romeo-juliet.fr
https://hello.romeojuliet.co.uk 
https://hello.romeo-jul-iet.fr 
https://hello.romeo-juliet.com
```

into this string `romeojuliet`

Basically want to get the alphabetic domain name with removing all other characters and `https://`, `com/co.uk/fr etc` Top Level Domains

Would be helpful if done using JS `replace`.
I tried till here

```js
let url="https://hello.romeo-juliet.fr";
const test=url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\/(\w+.)/, '');
console.log(test);
```

Comment: consider using a URL parser - also that is error prone to just get one of the segments of the domain.

Comment: Could the URL be similar to `https://hello.world.romeo-juliet.org`?

Comment: @DanielA.White it is known that one segment will always be `hello`

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, the URL will always two segments ie hello and {--domain name--}

Comment: i would just use `URL` then split on `.`

Comment: So, you want the substring from the first "." to the second ".", and replace all the dashes therein with nothing?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non regex solution:

Get the host of the URL (by parsing the string with the [`URL()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and getting its `host` property), split by a period and get the second item in the resulting array, then remove all occurences of `-`:

```js
let url="https://hello.romeo-juliet.fr";
const test = new URL(url).host.split(".")[1].replaceAll("-", '');
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with no regex as the following:

```
let url="https://hello.romeo-juliet.fr";
url.substring(url.indexOf(".")+1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
// result: romeo-juliet
```

I hope this answers your question